# Why does an effect on child component run again?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I would like some help please to understand why the code below is causing an inf render loop.
The way I see it, this should have been the cycle:

1. Render Container.
2. Render child StrRow.
3. Run effect for the first time and call update().
4. Change Container state.
5. Re-Render Container.
6. Re-Render chlid StrRow.
7. **DO NOT** run effect again as the dependency has not changed.

Yet, the effect seem to run after every render of StrRow.

```
function Container() {
      const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

      const update = React.useCallback(() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, [count, setCount]);

      return (
        <div style={{ background: "#ccc", border: "3px solid black" }}>
          Increced Length {count} Times.
          <StrRow update={update} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    function StrRow({ update }) {
      const [str, setStr] = React.useState(">");

      React.useEffect(() => {
        update();
      }, [str, update]);

      return (
        <div style={{ background: "#27b" }}>
          <div>{str}</div>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setStr(str + ">");
            }}
          >
            Add Length
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Here is a sandbox link with the update() call commented out to prevent the inf loop:
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-montalcini-muiod?file=/src/App.js

Please note that I am not looking for ways to fix or change this code. I would just like to understand the cause for the issue.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in the demo is slight different from what you have in the post.

Note that what you write in the post will not trigger an infinite loop and the onClick on child button will go through the following steps

- Update child str state
- Run child useEffect and calls parents update method
- update function increases count value and re-renders parent
- child component is re-rendered

However in the demo you have

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
    update();
  }, [str, update]);
```

The above useEffect however will cause an infinite loop. Reason being that when the update function is triggered it updates the state which basically leads to a new instance of update being created on re-render of Parent component as useCallback dependency has changed

The correct way to define the useCallback would have been to use `setCount` with functional pattern and not pass in count as a dependency of `useCallback` like below and everything would then work fine

```
  const update = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, [setCount]);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-yalow-q3ddk?file=/src/App.js:346-449)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, it's a copy paste from the demo. The only difference is that in the demo I commented out the update() call to prevent the loop. As I said, I don't mind the button click and I know the useEffect is the cause for the loop, and I know how to fix it. What I want to know is WHY this causes the loop. Why is the useEffect being triggered for the SECOND time after StrRow is rendered?

Comment: And I think I did explain everything that happens when you add str, update as a dependency to useEffect in child which causes an infinite loop

Comment: Update function reference changes when count is updated which is why child component useEffect is triggered again

Comment: But the value of str does not change between 1st and 2ed render... That is what I am confused about. Why is the effect fired if the dependency is the same?

Comment: Str does not change and adding it alone doesn't cause useEffect to run, it wil run as it is supposed to. Only when you add update as dependency to useEffect, it will be called again. Your demo and your post have different codes and I think that is why you are confused

Comment: But update function is wrapped in useCallback. Shouldn't that preserve the reference?

Comment: Yes but it's reference is dependent on count, which changes and hence the reference changes. Please read the post carefully

Comment: Ohhhh now I get it. And yes, the autofix added the update dependency to my demo after I posted the code here. You are right. Sorry, and thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

this is because `update` setsState which causes a rerender, which renders your `<StrRow>` component to rendered, which onMount in `useEffect` calls that update function which setState..etc and will continue to do so forever

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know already that this is the cause. I would like to know WHY. Why does the useEffect being triggered again at THE SECOND time? str has not changed.